# Are application for windows ce 5.0 suitable for use on windows ce 6.5?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, .net-3.5

I have developing an application for Windows CE 5.0 using VB on VS2008.

My co-worker want to buy a new device with Windows CE 6.5 OS and want the IT to install the same app as old device.

Before he buy the new device, i want to make sure is the application (VB.Net) for windows ce 5.0 suitable for use on windows ce 6.5?

Comment: [.NET Compact Framework 3.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=65&e6b34bbe-475b-1abd-2c51-b5034bcdd6d2=True) is available for Windows CE5.0 and higher, so the answer should be yes.

Comment: thanks for a relief answer.

Answer (score 2):

It should work. but it's not granted. If you used only features from the .NET runtime, then you should have no issues. If you invoked some OS API directly those may not be available on a different device. Windows CE (the core of Windows Mobile 6.5) is heavily customizable, so it's not granted that two devices with different OS images provide all the same features.
.NET works on top of that, so if you used only .NET CF features, those should be available on both devices and will allow your app to run.
Microsoft used to provide a device emulator for WM6.5, it's probably still there, hidden somewhere on their site (maybe inside WM6.5 SDK), this will allow you to test your app without buying a real device.